# Design question for flask real-time messages

Tags: flask, websocket, flask-socketio

My question relates primarily to website design.  As a novice programmer, I would like to have a tab in my flask website dedicated to serving real-time messages (likely using pika and a remote rabbitmq server).  The reason for this is to serve the visitors real-time information without them having to refresh on the site.

I'm using Blueprints, and the reading i've done shows that the integration of flask-socketio and blueprints is far from elementary, so i'm wondering if there are easier options to push updates out to the end user.  Should i create websockets directly?  Is this easier in a flask blueprint environment?  Should i use long polling?  What might be the preferred route here?

Comment: Server Sent Events would work for one-way messaging to a browser.  The javascript required to receive messages is minimal, and you could add some vanilla JS to update the tab.  I found [a repo which implements chartjs](https://github.com/roniemartinez/real-time-charts-with-flask) and [another which implments chat](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/chat).  Both worth reading the code for.  The latter uses redis pub/sub which could probably be adapted to suit [rabbitmq pub/sub](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html).

Comment: Thank you!  I will read more about this.